# Scrape data sorting by conditional list

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I am working on the data scrape from web and try to structure those data with BRAND, MODEL, PN...etc.

Read [How to extract brand from product name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047569/how-to-extract-brand-from-product-name)
and Found there isn't a way to do it all by computer so I decide to do with both human and computer.

Raw data Example: ['NOKIA 5.3 phone (black)', 'NOKIA 5.3 phone  (white)', 'NOKIA 5.3 phone ']

```
def textbetween(text):
     s = text
     start = '('
     end = ')'
     s_int = s.find(start,3)
     s_end = s.find(end,3)+1
     found = s[s_int:s_end]
     return found
def textcheck(TEXT):
     spec_temp = textbetween(TEXT)
     remove_spec = TEXT.replace(spec_temp, '')
     check = remove_spec.split(' ')
     return check
```

After above I will get a list of word list and use for loop to read it from raw data[1, 2, 3...]

And I trying to make some empty list and use condition to

```
raw = ['NOKIA 5.3 phone (black)', 'NOKIA 5.3 phone  (white)', 'NOKIA 5.3 phone ']
BRAND = []
MODEL = []
PN = []
OTHER = []
for i in raw:
   check = textcheck(i)
   for temp in check:
      while temp not in BRAND or MODEL or PN:
      print(temp, '<=Brand? leave blank if no, or type anything as Yes')
      human= input()
      if human!= '':
          print('this is a brand, add to brand list')
          BRAND.append(temp)
          break
      elif human == '':
          print(temp, '<=Model? leave blank if no, or type anything as Yes')
          human= input()
          if human!= '':
              print('this is a model, add to model list')
              MODEL.append(temp)
              break
          elif human== '':
              print(temp, '<=PN? leave blank if no, or type anything as Yes')
              human= input()
              if human!= '':
                  print('this is a PN, add to PN list')
                  PN.append(temp)
                  break
              else:
                 print('Do nothing')
                 break
           else:
              pass
       else:
         pass
```

With above condition, I should get a list of BRAND, MODEL, PN - Human to define at the first time, machine to check if the word is in the BRAND list and any raw data can stream to this structure.
So far the define empty list doesn't work - After I run this first product name, the BRAND already have NOKIA but the 2nd time the machine ask me again which NOKIA is already in the list. Because the list is dynamic base on the input raw data and human define, how can I run this and make the condition works for sorting the data?

And planning to export the list excel like

1. raw data: NOKIA 5.3 phone (black) BRAND: NOKIA MODEL: 5.3 PN: --
2. BRAND LIST (storage for further use)
3. MODEL LIST (storage for further use)

[Expect Output Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPsLQ.png)

RAW data update
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SHLKqOLjL5wJpkEoC_C_peD3Ogwt8tVS?usp=sharing

Comment: what do you expect as a output ??

Comment: BRAND, MODEL, PN, OTHER => to excel. mainly is to ensure the raw data can be sort by the condition made for the lists.

Comment: @wiskinglin post expected output from 'Raw data Example'

Comment: @ Zaraki Kenpachi. Updated as pic something like this in excel. thank

Comment: @wiskinglin post some example data that contains PN and different Brand

Comment: Not sure if you can read this, https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SHLKqOLjL5wJpkEoC_C_peD3Ogwt8tVS?usp=sharing

Comment: @wiskinglin you need to define many conditions to parse this messy string to desired output. First clean foreign signs then try to split text.

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi RAW DATA updated, not more foreign signs

Comment: @wiskinglin now you need to show where each part of Brand, Model, PN, and Other is start and finish. For example how you will split this data `HP 14s-dq1009TU (14/i5-1035 G1/8G/512GB PCIe/W10/FHD)`? and others

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I was trying to find the naming rule for the strings but there isn't one. So the idea is to use the have human to define the string is BRAND, MODEL, PN or Other for few times and machine to detect if the coming string include those word that have be classified to each conditional list.

Comment: For example: HP 14s-dq1009TU (14/i5-1035 G1/8G/512GB PCIe/W10/FHD) is the first string, I remove the () in the beginning. than the HP can be classified to BRAND, the 2nd time a string with HP inside that can be auto filter by machine, each brand doesn't have so much model and PN, I assume if this code can work I only need to define 20 times for a BRAND so I can get all the model of 1 brand.

By the time the database grown up, less human define needs to be made.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @wiskinglin hmm.. for `ASUS VivoBook S14 S432FL-0082E8265U  (i5-8265U/8G/MX250-2G/512G PCIe/W10/FHD/14)` will by proper to split like this: brand - ASUS VivoBoo, model - S14, pn - S432FL-0082E8265U , rest from ()?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi Brand: ASUS Model: VivoBook, S14, PN: S432FL-0082E8265U , rest from (), if you would like to keep the (), it can be classified to OTHER.

Answer (score 0):

Try this =^..^=
This will parse string and split data into desired variables.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Example_RAW.xlsx')
df_results = pd.DataFrame()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    parts = row[0].split('(')

    data_list = parts[0].split(' ')
    data_list = list(filter(None, data_list))

    # get brand
    brand = data_list[0]
    # get model
    model =' '.join([x for x in data_list if len(x) < 9][1:])
    # get pn
    pn_find = [x for x in data_list if len(x) > 9]
    if len(pn_find) > 0:
        pn = pn_find[0]
    else:
        pn = ''
    # get opther
    if len(parts) == 2:
        other = parts[1].replace(')', '')
    else:
        other = ''

    # collect data
    collected_data = {'brand': brand, 'model': model, 'pn': pn, 'other': other}
    data = pd.Series(collected_data)
    df_results = df_results.append(data, ignore_index=True)

df_results.to_csv('collected_data.csv')
```

output:

```
  brand       model                                            other                   pn
0  ASUS                            i5-10210U/8G/512G PCIe/W10/FHD/14   X420FA-0108S10210U
1  ASUS  ZenBook 14                i7-1065G7/8G/512G PCIe/W10/FHD/14  UX425JA-0052G1065G7
2    HP                          14/i5-1035 G1/8G/512GB PCIe/W10/FHD         14s-dq1009TU
3    HP                            i5-10210U/8G/512G PCIe/W10/FHD/14         14s-cf2006TU
4  ASUS              i5-1035G1/4G/MX110-2G/1T+256G PCIe/W10/FHD/15.6   X509JB-0111S1035G1
```

Comment: Thanks, i will use it as a function for some of the string data. I am still working with my design and will update it as well.